# Oracle, изменение типа секционирования(партиционнирования) таблицы

Tags: oracle, partition

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, знающие люди.
Есть таблица с секционированием(range) по дате1 на кварталы.
Необходимо теперь сделать двойное секционирование:

1. по дате1 на года;
2. по дате2 на кварталы(внутри каждого года);

Получается, нужна Composite Range-Range Partition.
Но таблица изначально была создана не как composite и теперь при попытке добавления subpartition ругается на это.
Основной вопрос: можно ли без создания таблицы заново(так как придётся перезагружать большое кол-во информации), только с помощью alter изменить тип секционирования таблицы на composite? 
Версия Oracle 11.2.0.4.0
Вы меня очень выручите, если подскажите!

Comment: Надеюсь, это секционирование по разным столбцам? А то из постановки не очень ясно.

Comment: Да, разумеется, извиняюсь что не уточнил.

Comment: Честно говоря, надежда (и то небольшая) только на online redefinition. Серверу БД данные всё равно придётся переносить, т.е. искать в секции строки для подсекций и перемещать их куда-то. Если бы подсекции ужи были, можно было попробовать хитрый change subpartition template, а тут даже не знаю. Exchange partiton не подходит?

Comment: А можно подробней про Exchange? я пробовал какие то но может неправильно пробовал. 
Пробовал даже реализовать пример [отсюда](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76956/partiti.htm) из раздела Exchanging a Hash-Partitioned Table with a Composite Partition, но почему то даже пример реализовать не удалось

Comment: А дата1 и дата2 - это одинаковая дата, которая дублицируется, виртуальные колонки, или две разные независимые даты?

Comment: это две разные даты...точней так, дата1 - это обобщённая до месяца дата(например 01.02.2016 для всего февраля) а дата2 это уже точная дата с конкретным временем

Answer (score 2):

Если еще нужно, слепил какой-то велосипед. Индексы, конечно придеться сносить и пересоздавать (ну локальные как ни крути пересоздавать, ключи партиционирования меняются). В общем, идея перегонами через Exchange Partition с доп. таблицами перекинуть данные в результирущую T$_TARGET. Ну а потом ренейм.
На тестовых данных отработало. Ну и что мне не нравится в этом подходе, это возможные проблемы в случае падения скрипта на середине, где делаются Exchange Partition, ибо данные частично будут в новой структуре, частично в старой, надо будет попотеть все выровнять =(. 
Вот сам скрипт:

```
-- create source table:
create table ag_table_source (number_field number, date_field1 date, date_field2 date, varchar2_field varchar2(64))
partition by range (date_field1)
(partition p_2014_one values less than (to_date('01.04.2014','dd.mm.yyyy'))
,partition p_2014_two values less than (to_date('01.07.2014','dd.mm.yyyy'))
,partition p_2014_three values less than (to_date('01.10.2014','dd.mm.yyyy'))
,partition p_2014_four values less than (to_date('01.01.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'))

,partition p_2015_one values less than (to_date('01.04.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'))
,partition p_2015_two values less than (to_date('01.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'))
,partition p_2015_three values less than (to_date('01.10.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'))
,partition p_2015_four values less than (to_date('01.01.2016','dd.mm.yyyy'))

,partition p_2016_one values less than (to_date('01.04.2016','dd.mm.yyyy'))
,partition p_2016_two values less than (to_date('01.07.2016','dd.mm.yyyy'))
,partition p_2016_three values less than (to_date('01.10.2016','dd.mm.yyyy'))
,partition p_2016_four values less than (to_date('01.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy'))
)

-- fill source table by test data:
insert into ag_table_source (number_field, date_field1, date_field2, varchar2_field)
select level,
       trunc(to_date('01.01.2014','dd.mm.yyyy') + 30*level,'MONTH'),
       to_date('01.01.2014','dd.mm.yyyy') + 30*level,
       'test_value_' || level
from dual
connect by to_date('01.01.2014','dd.mm.yyyy') + 30*level < to_date('01.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy');

-- run exchange partition chain
declare
  -- types
  type tr_part_list is record (name varchar2(30)
                              ,high_value varchar2(256));
  type tt_part_list is table of tr_part_list;
  type tr_list is record (year_high_value varchar2(256)
                         ,year_part_name varchar2(30)
                         ,part_list tt_part_list default tt_part_list());
  type tt_list is table of tr_list index by pls_integer;
  -- configurations
  c_action varchar2(10) := /*'EXECUTE'*/ 'PRINT'; -- "PRINT" or "EXECUTE"
  c_table_source varchar2(30) := 'AG_TABLE_SOURCE'; --source table name in upper case
  c_date1_field varchar2(30) := 'DATE_FIELD1'; --field "дата1" from your table
  c_date2_field varchar2(30) := 'DATE_FIELD2'; --field "дата2" from your table
  -- patterns
  c_target_table  varchar2(30) := 'T$_TARGET';
  c_source_mirror varchar2(30) := 'T$_SOURCE_MIRROR';
  c_target_mirror varchar2(30) := 'T$_TARGET_MIRROR';
  c_exch_pattern varchar2(4000) := 'ALTER TABLE [part_table] EXCHANGE PARTITION [partition] WITH TABLE [table] WITHOUT VALIDATION';
  c_drop_pattern varchar2(4000) := 'DROP TABLE [table_name]';
  c_partition_pattern varchar2(4000) := 'PARTITION [partition] VALUES LESS THAN ([high_value]),';
  c_subpartition_pattern varchar2(4000) := 'SUBPARTITION [subpartition] VALUES LESS THAN ([high_value]),';
  c_date_mask varchar2(30) := 'dd.mm.yyyy';
  c_hv_pattern varchar2(4000) := 'TO_DATE(''[date]'',''' || c_date_mask || ''')';
  -- variables
  v_create_pattern clob;
  v_create_curr varchar2(32000);
  v_create_sql varchar2(32000);
  v_hv_source date;
  v_year_hv date;
  v_list tt_list;
  v_date date;
  v_year number;
  v_part varchar2(32000);
  v_subpart varchar2(32000);
  -- methods
  procedure p_run (ip_sql in varchar2, ip_action varchar2 default c_action) is
  begin
    case
      when ip_action = 'PRINT'
      then dbms_output.put_line (ip_sql);
      when ip_action = 'EXECUTE'
      then execute immediate ip_sql;
    end case;
  end p_run;
begin
  -- get create pattern:
  v_create_pattern := dbms_metadata.get_ddl (object_type => 'TABLE', name => c_table_source);
  v_create_pattern := replace(v_create_pattern,'"','');
  v_create_pattern := replace(v_create_pattern,upper(user) || '.','');
  v_create_pattern := substr(v_create_pattern, 1, instr(v_create_pattern, 'PARTITION BY RANGE', 1) - 1);
  v_create_pattern := replace(v_create_pattern, c_table_source, '[table_name]');

  -- create mirror for source table:
  dbms_output.put_line ('  --## Create source_mirror table');
  v_create_curr := replace(v_create_pattern, '[table_name]', c_source_mirror);
  p_run (v_create_curr);

  -- fill collection with all needful information
  for i in (select p.partition_name
                  ,p.high_value
            from user_tab_partitions p
            where p.table_name = c_table_source
            order by p.partition_position)
    loop
      execute immediate 'select ' || i.high_value || ' from dual' into v_hv_source;
      v_hv_source := v_hv_source - 1;
      v_year_hv := trunc(add_months (v_hv_source, 12), 'YEAR');
      v_year := to_number(to_char(v_year_hv,'yyyy'));
      v_list(v_year).year_high_value := replace(c_hv_pattern,'[date]',to_char(v_year_hv,c_date_mask));
      v_list(v_year).year_part_name := 'YEAR_' || v_year;
      v_list(v_year).part_list.extend;
      v_list(v_year).part_list(v_list(v_year).part_list.count).name := i.partition_name;
      v_list(v_year).part_list(v_list(v_year).part_list.count).high_value := replace(c_hv_pattern,'[date]',to_char(v_hv_source,c_date_mask));
    end loop;

   -- create target table:
  dbms_output.put_line ('  --## Create target table');
  v_create_curr := replace(v_create_pattern, '[table_name]', c_target_table);
  v_create_curr := v_create_curr || chr(10) || 
                   'PARTITION BY RANGE (' || c_date1_field || ') SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (' || c_date2_field || ') (' || chr(10);
  v_year := v_list.first; 
  while (v_year is not null)
    loop
      v_subpart := null;
      v_part := replace(replace(c_partition_pattern
                               ,'[partition]', v_list(v_year).year_part_name)
                       ,'[high_value]', v_list(v_year).year_high_value);
      v_part := rtrim(v_part,',') || chr(10);
      for i in 1..v_list(v_year).part_list.count
        loop
          v_subpart := v_subpart || chr(10) || replace(replace(c_subpartition_pattern
                                                              ,'[subpartition]', v_list(v_year).part_list(i).name)
                                                      ,'[high_value]', v_list(v_year).part_list(i).high_value);
        end loop;
      v_subpart := rtrim(v_subpart, ',');
      v_create_curr := v_create_curr || chr(10) || v_part || '(' || v_subpart || '),';
      v_year := v_list.next(v_year);
    end loop;
  v_create_curr := rtrim(v_create_curr,',') || ')';
  p_run (v_create_curr);

  v_year := v_list.first; 
  while (v_year is not null)
    loop
       -- create target_mirror table:
      dbms_output.put_line ('  --## Create target_mirror table');
      v_create_curr := replace(v_create_pattern, '[table_name]', c_target_mirror);
      v_create_curr := v_create_curr || chr(10) || 'PARTITION BY RANGE (' || c_date2_field || ') (' || chr(10);
      v_part := null;
      for i in 1..v_list(v_year).part_list.count
        loop
          v_part := v_part || chr(10) || replace(replace(c_partition_pattern
                                                        ,'[partition]', v_list(v_year).part_list(i).name)
                                                ,'[high_value]', v_list(v_year).part_list(i).high_value);
        end loop;
      v_part := rtrim(v_part,',') || ')';
      v_create_curr := v_create_curr || v_part;
      p_run (v_create_curr);

      -- start exchange partition chain:
      for i in 1..v_list(v_year).part_list.count
        loop
          v_create_curr := replace(replace(replace(c_exch_pattern
                                                  ,'[part_table]', c_table_source)
                                          ,'[partition]', v_list(v_year).part_list(i).name)
                                  ,'[table]', c_source_mirror);
          p_run (v_create_curr);

          v_create_curr := replace(replace(replace(c_exch_pattern
                                                  ,'[part_table]', c_target_mirror)
                                          ,'[partition]', v_list(v_year).part_list(i).name)
                                  ,'[table]', c_source_mirror);
          p_run (v_create_curr);
        end loop;
      v_create_curr := replace(replace(replace(c_exch_pattern
                                              ,'[part_table]', c_target_table)
                                      ,'[partition]', v_list(v_year).year_part_name)
                              ,'[table]', c_target_mirror);
      p_run (v_create_curr);

      v_create_curr := replace(c_drop_pattern, '[table_name]', c_target_mirror);
      p_run (v_create_curr);

      v_year := v_list.next(v_year);
    end loop;
end;
```